# EF getting mapped column name from string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have three entities that share a common base class. Each of the entities have their own Map class for my context and load just fine. Each entity has a different primary key name which I rename in the base class so I can use generic methods of the the three entities while using the same property name.

Everything maps fine when going to the database, for example I can do `db.Vehicle.Where(v => v.VehicleID < 100)` and it translates to the DB column name which is different than `VehicleID`.

The problem is I am now wanting to go the opposite direction. So for example I might have the string `"Length"` but in one table it might be `Length1` and in another `Length2`. I want to use the same mapping I used in the model builder to be able to translate `"Length"` into whatever the corresponding value would be based on the (`v => v.Length`) property in the base class.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

if you have already tried this fluent API and it did not work, then I recommend declaring the property as virtual.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ConcreteClass1>()
.Property(f => f.Length)
                .HasColumnName("Length1");

modelBuilder.Entity<ConcreteClass2>()
.Property(f => f.Length)
                .HasColumnName("Length2");
```

Comment: Yes I understand mapping with the model builder but lets say I am given the string "Length", I would then like some way to use EF to map that string value to the string "Length1" for ConcreateClass1 and "Length2" for ConcreateClass2. The reason being is I am making a template to display different vehicle types and I would like to specify in a profile only 1 value that could then be mapped somehow through EF to the appropriate name of the column in the database. How does EF know to change .Where(f => f.Length) into "Length1" when it generates the SQL?

Comment: <<How does EF know to change .Where(f => f.Length) into "Length1" when it generates the SQL?>> We are telling modelBuilder the column name  via HasColumnName function, that is how EF knows what the column name for a property is. I do not understand what your question is.

Comment: Is there a way that I can access that lookup table that I make with the model builder? So if I have a property I can get the mapped string name?